# age persistence in information technology

Tags: usa

My goal is to understand persistence of employment in the information technology sector over age groups. For example, for the person who enters IT at age 21, are they still employed in that sector at 31? 41? 51? 61? And, to put all this in **context**, how does the rate of career persistence compare to other U.S. sectors like finance, real estate, trades, health care, sales, education, etc?

Before I try to start from scratch, **does this duplicate previous work**?

Comment: Are you looking for data? Your question does not say that. And the question "does this duplicate previous work" is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I have found exactly two places to ask a statistics question. This is the second. Can you please clarify which site would be appropriate?

Comment: relevant? https://flowingdata.com/2017/11/28/career-paths/ (includes data source)